# Application of Implicit Function Theorem to $f(x,t)=x^3\log(t^2+1)+e^x-t$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, implicit-function-theorem

Consider a function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by
$$
\begin{equation}
f(x,t)=x^3\log(t^2+1)+e^x-t.
\end{equation}
$$
Show that for each value of $t$ there is a function $g_t$ such that $$f(g_t(y),t)=y.$$
Also, Show that near $(x,t)=(0,0)$, the equation $f(x,t)=1$ defines $t$ as function of $x$ such that $$f(x, x(t))=1$$ near $x=0$.

**MY APPROACH:**

Here, $f(x,t)=0$ doesn't have any solution, also $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,t)=3x^2\log(t^2+1)+e^x\neq 0.$ Therefore, by implicit function theorem, there exist a function $g$ as function of $t$.
But I am not sure, how to find $g_t(y)$ such that $$f(g_t(y),t)=y.$$

Please give me some idea, how to approach such problem if there is no solution of $f(x,t)=0$.

Comment: why are you looking at $f=0$? the question looks to be about $f=1$

Comment: If we write $t$ as $x(t)$ then we need to look at $f(x,t)=1$. Am I right?

Comment: $$f(0, 1) = 0$$

Comment: Oh!! Thanks! I got it. But how to calculate $g_t$ ?